# Can't generate table from entity Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

Please help !!! I can't generated table from entities**:

```
// class Application
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;

@EntityScan("sb.entity")
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

```
// class Entity
package sb.entity;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "category")
public class CategoryEntity {
    
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    
    @Column(name = "code")
    private String code;

}
```

```
// application.properties
server.port=8081

spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/springboot_database
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = hoa123456
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create-drop 

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

```
// file pom.xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>sb</groupId>
    <artifactId>sb</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <mysql.version>8.0.13</mysql.version>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>${mysql.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**This is console:**  I seach on overstack but i just add spring-boot-starter-data-jpa already.

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: At least one JPA metamodel must be present!
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:742) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
at sb.api.Application.main(Application.java:11) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: At least one JPA metamodel must be present!
at org.springframework.util.Assert.notEmpty(Assert.java:277) ~[spring-core-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.mapping.JpaMetamodelMappingContext.(JpaMetamodelMappingContext.java:52) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaMetamodelMappingContextFactoryBean.createInstance(JpaMetamodelMappingContextFactoryBean.java:71) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaMetamodelMappingContextFactoryBean.createInstance(JpaMetamodelMappingContextFactoryBean.java:26) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.AbstractFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractFactoryBean.java:134) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
... 16 common frames omitted

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XU8mc.png)**

Comment: In which package is Application ?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli  I just add image for my project, please watch and help me

Comment: If you move Application to sb package then you will not need any of the *Scan annotations. Please try that

Comment: Stop mixing jars from different versions of a framework. You are mixing Hibernate 4 and Hibernate 5 and wonder why it doesn't work... Just remove the `org.hibernate` dpendencies those are already managed by the `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` module.

Comment: try adding @ComponentScan("base package name") and @Configuration annotations to main class since all are in different packages you need to mention explicitly

Comment: Thanks all your guys, I just follow up your suggestion but it still not works. Please come here to help me. I'm so hopeless:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63116577/cant-generate-table-from-entity-on-spring-boot

Answer (score 1):

When you create an Entity, you need to provide @Id annotation. This is mandatory. I am assuming you are getting error because of the same. Can you try creating entity as

```
package sb.entity;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "category")
public class CategoryEntity {
    
@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    Long id;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    
    @Column(name = "code")
    private String code;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure you have that you have the Application class package in correctly placed under package. For example if you have your Application.java( which has main) under com.sb, then Sb.java entity class should be under com.sb package.

## Another example

com.sb --> Application.java

com.sb.enity --> CategoryEntity.java

com.notscanned.test --> NotScannedCategoryEntity .java

The hierarchy matters , anything under com.sb.* will be autoscanned by spring.

Hope this solves your problem.